# 'strings' comparison between a static array of chars and another one sent via socket

Tags: c, linux, arrays, sockets, char

I'm trying to validate 2 strings over socket tcp but I can't figure out what am I doing wrong so the strings I try to compare using strcmp are:

header:

```
struct message{
    char n[32];
    int flag;
};
```

in server:

```
char names[3][32];
strcpy(passs[0], "111");

int z;
printf("checking data\n");
for(z=0 ; z<3; z++){
    if (strcmp(&m.n, names[z]) == 0){
        printf("name found\n");
    }
}
```

in client:

```
struct message m;
fgets(m.n, 32, stdin);
send(cSock, &m, sizeof(m),0);
```

ps: I tried to give only the essential codelines, since the program is a client/server tcp example with threads.

Comment: You probably need to provide an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) so that people can help.  One of the things you can do to help yourself is print out what you're comparing...that may tell you more of what's up.

Comment: What is `m` in the loop above? If it's a `message` structure, what is `m.p`?

Comment: m.p is part of the structure I didn't wanted to share sry...

Comment: probablly but this is pure c in hadeling char arrays for comparison... there is no error, or warning ateast.... but i think it the wahy puts sets values until the 32'th elemnt where is \0 and how my strcpy saves them may have something to do with it

Comment: Try running in a debugger, and step through the code line by line while checking variables and strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `fgets(m.n, 32, stdin);` reads fewer than 32 characters from stdin, then the newline will be present at the end, and will be sent through the socket.  Nothing read from `fgets(m.n, 32, stdin);` will ever match "111" because that is length 3 and is not ended by a newline.

Solution: truncate the newline after you do your `fgets`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize all of the elements of `char names[3][32]`: if you don't, reading from them is Undefined Behavior, and anything could happen:

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    names[i][0] = 0;  // Initialize to the empty string
```